# zsh: Read from stdin until a string delimiter

Tags: shell, zsh, string, read, shell-builtin

I want to read from `stdin` until a string delimiter `MARKER=$'\0'"BRISH_MARKER"`  is encountered. I tried:

```
❯ unset br ; print -rn -- hi${MARKER}world |   {  IFS= read -d "$MARKER" -r br ; cat -v } ; echo ; typeset -p br
```

Which gives:

```
BRISH_MARKERworld
typeset br=hi
```

So `read` is only using the first character of the given delimiter, `\0`. I want it to use the whole string. How can I achieve this?

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a process that continuously feeds a stream of data to a zsh process, and the data needs to be broken into different values using a delimiter. I was originally using just `\0`, but that won't allow me to use values that contain `\0`, so I am trying to use the current `MARKER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `read -d` works only with single-character delimiters (in `bash` and `ksh93`, it only works with single-*byte* delimiters).

Reading up to a delimiter also means that you need to read one byte at a time (especially with non-seekable inputs such as pipes) to make sure you don't read *past* the delimiter, which makes it inefficient.

I'd suggest using `length:value` records instead:

```
write-record() {
  set -o localoptions +o multibyte
  print -rn -- "$#1:$1"
}
read-record() {
  set -o localoptions +o multibyte
  local len

  # note that in current versions of zsh, read -k0 (for empty records)
  # returns a non-zero exit status.
  eval "$1="
  IFS= read -rd: len || return
  ((len == 0)) || read -u0 -k "$len" "$1"
}
```

(disabling `multibyte` locally in those to work with length in byte and avoid the useless character encoding/decoding here).

Then as an example:

```
$ (write-record $'é\0x'; write-record $'foo\0MARKER') | { read-record a && read-record b; printf "<%q>\n" "$a" "$b"; }
<é$'\0'x>
<foo$'\0'MARKER>
```