# bash: Read from stdin until a string delimiter

Tags: bash, text-processing

Let's say I have two files containing arbitrary bytes: `./delimiter` and `./data`.

I want to read from `./data` up to and excluding the first occurrence of the byte sequence in `./delimiter`.

How would I do this using Bash?

Example:

- Content of `./delimiter`

  ```
  world
  ```
- Content of `./data`

  ```
  helloworld
  ```
- Expected result:

  ```
  hello
  ```

Similar/Equivalent Question:

- [zsh: Read from stdin until a string delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607266/zsh-read-from-stdin-until-a-string-delimiter)

Note: `read -d delim` does not solve my problem, because it only support a single-character delimiter, not a string. Also, it stores the result in a variable, and variables don't support `NUL` bytes. I want the output on `stdout`.

Comment: Can both the files be multiline?

Comment: And what should be done with that data that was read? Should it be output somewhere? Stored in a bash variable (note that bash variables can't store NUL bytes).

Comment: @choroba The files contain arbitrary binary data, they are not text files. There should be no interpretation of the content as ascii text (other than the usual). In particular, the files don't contain "lines" in any sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the data should be output on stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e 'local $/;
         open $de, "<", "delimiter" or die $!;
         $/ = <$de>;
         open $da, "<", "data" or die $!;
         chomp( $first = <$da> );
         print $first;'
```

The special variable [$/](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#IO::Handle-%3Einput_record_separator(-EXPR-)) sets the input record separator, by [local](http://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#local)ising it, we will read the whole file (also called "slurping"). We then use the diamond operator to read from the `delimiter` file, and set the separator to its content. We then read the first record from the `data` file, [chomp](http://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#chomp)ing the record separator from it.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` (the only shell that can store arbitrary byte sequences in its variables), assuming `data` and `delimiter` are regular (or at least mmap()able) files, you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile

set +o multibyte # necessary so sequences of bytes that
                 # happen to form valid characters may be
                 # broken in the middle if necessary.

firstpart=${mapfile[data]%%$mapfile[delimiter]*}
```

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
set +o multibyte # necessary so sequences of bytes that
                 # happen to form valid characters may be
                 # broken in the middle if necessary.

delimiter=$mapfile[delimiter]
parts=( ${(ps[$delimiter])mapfile[data]} )

firstpart=$parts[1]
```

(don't expect it to be very efficient nor to scale well to files larger than a few hundred megabytes).

To print that part verbatim, use:

```
print -rn -- $firstpart
```

Or

```
printf %s $firstpart
```